# Can someone please share a extremely simple version of JQuery Ajax with pagination?

Tags: jquery, pagination

Can someone please share a extremely simple version of JQuery Ajax with pagination??

Comment: What do you mean, "with pagination"?

Comment: I have a database with 10k rows, I want to list 50 rows per page, so it would be ideal to have a sexy jquery function that calls a "load-data.php"  with a page number and that file returns 50 rows from the database. 

So the end product would be a simple page with a table containing 50 rows of data and below the table I would like to have 1,2,3,4 ..so once I click on a number 2 it loads page 2 of 50 rows from the 10k db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the server to take care of pagination, as in it should respond with the correct output based on the received `pageNo` parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $("#results").load( "foo.php", { pageNo: $(this).text()}, sortBy: $("#sortBy").val() );
        return false;
    });
});

<select id="sortBy">
    <option value="date">Added</option>
    <option value="price">Price</option>
</select>

<div id="results"></div>

<a href="foo.php?p=1">1</a>
<a href="foo.php?p=2">2</a>
```

Note: When an object is passed as the second argument to `$.load`, a POST request will be made. See http://api.jquery.com/load/

EDIT: The same as above, but fetching JSON from the server:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $.getJSON( "foo.php", { pageNo: $(this).text(), sortBy: $("#sortBy").val() }, function(json) {
            // read json here, possibly using $.each
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

EDIT(again): I would recommend using the server to render in the initial content. If you insist on requesting the first page of results with ajax, one way is to simulate the clicking of the link for page 1:

```
$("a:first").click();
```

better you give your pagination links a class, say `.pageNo`, to eliminate any confusion:

```
$("a.pageNo:first").click();
```

Comment: Add this to a click event on the pagination links. Make the pageNo variable dynamic by setting the text() value of the pagination link to it.

Comment: that worked so nicely!! how can I rewrite it so the function accepts a json object?


in my foo.php I have "echo json_encode($arr);"


by the way, do you think its a good idea to query the databse in foo.php and then convert it into json and then retreieve json on the mainpage and then parse through the resultset and present it??

Comment: @vick - it really depends. It's normally simpler to just send the output in its entirety to the client, I normally use json for more complex tasks.

Comment: ok, but if I want to rewrite it so it gets the json object, how can I do that?

Comment: @vick - done. Have a look at the docs for jQuery.each for looping over a json object.

Comment: @vick - there are many ways to get json from the server, including `$.postJSON` and `$.ajax` with the 'dataType' option set to 'json'. I would suggest reading through the ajax section of the jQuery API.

Comment: thanks! great!

can I make it call page 1 by default when the page loads?

Comment: @karim: sorry for bugging you so much and I really apprecaite the help. I got it to work fine! And i decided not to use the json feature. My next goal is to being able to pass variable from php to JQuery and then on to my data-loader. I want to pass variables such as page, sort_by etc..

Comment: @vick - You're not bugging me (I do this voluntarily :). I've edited the answer, to include a select element which lets the user decide how the page should be sorted. The selected value is sent to the server along with the page number. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination